# Angular2 - Adding routerLink parameters to chosen table value

Tags: angular, html-table, angular2-routing, routerlink

I have a routerLink attached to the lead value in a table I have created in the HTML of an angular2 component.  Upon clicking that table value, I want the routerLink to not only send to the next component but also bring the chosen value to the next component.

Example of current code

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Records']" ><td> {{Member.Name}} <td></a>
```

I have the link so it is sending to the Records page, however how do I send the name to that component so that I can display the specific record that I am trying to display?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a route parameter to the `url` and then access that value using the `ActivatedRoute`.

Route Definition

```
{ path: "Records/:name", component: RecordsComponent }
```

Link

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Records', Member.Name]" ><td> {{Member.Name}} <td></a>
```

Get Value

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class RecordsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this._route.params.subscribe((params) => {
        var recordName = params["name"];
        //load record data
   });
}
```

Comment: What is the import that I need to use to be able to implement OnInit?

Comment: import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';

Comment: I have correctly implement OnInit and am no longer getting an error, however, I am getting another error that says it cannot find the name ngOnInit.

Comment: Yes that did it! Now just one more question: is there a way that I can use that recordName variable outside of the ngOnInIt function? (I am trying to send that name to an api call function in the same component)

Comment: You could make recordName a property on your component and set it as `this.recordName = ...` or just all the API with the. And you received inside the subscription to the route params.

Comment: Thank you, Teddy, I am forever in debt to you.

Answer (score 4):

define your route like this:

```
{ path: 'Records/:id', component: xxx }
```

declaratively:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Records', Member.name]">{{ Member.name }}</a>
```

programmatically:

```
goToMemberDetails(name) {
   this.router.navigate(['/Records', name]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class RecordsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this._route.params.subscribe((params) => {
        var recordName = params["name"];
        //load record data
   });
}
```